# Split each row of a pcollection into multiple pcollections?

Tags: python, apache-beam

After I do some processing and a group by key, I have a dataset like the one below. I now need to do some processing on each row of the data to get the output below. I have tried flatmap it is really slow because the length of the "value" list can be arbitrarily long. I figured I can split each row into separate pcollections, process in parallel and then flatten them together. How can I split each row into a different pcollection? If that isn't feasible, is there another way I can speed up computation?

Input

```
key, value
1    [A, B, B, B]
2    [A, B, B, B]
3    [A, B, B, B]
4    [A, B, B, B]
5    [A, B, B, B]
```

Output:

```
key, value
1    (A, 0)
1    (B, 1)
1    (B, 2)
1    (B, 3)
2    (A, 0)
2    (B, 1)
2    (B, 2)
2    (B, 3)
...
```

Comment: Why not just to iterate over the values in the result of GBK? 
Many PCollections don't make sense to me (only if they contains the elements of different types and have to follow the different path pf downstream processing) since PCollection by design is supposed to be processed in parallel.

Comment: I did try that. I wrote a function and applied that function to the pcollection using flatmap and it's really slow and sometimes runs out of memory. The length of "value" lists can be arbitrarily long (hundreds of thousands). I was hoping splitting it into multiple pcollections would help speed things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the Apache Beam model, it is a common misconception that the parallelization scheme is defined by the PCollection (understandable since this is short for Parallel Collection). In actuality, the parallelization is defined *per key* in each PCollection[1]. In other words, the Beam model processes keys in parallel but values in a single key sequentially.

The problem you are coming up against is commonly referred to as a hot key. This happens when too many values are paired to a single key, thus limiting parallelism.

To manipulate the data to the expected output you will have to edit your existing pipeline to emit the values in such a way that not all elements go to a single key. This is a little tough because it looks like in your example you wish to output the index with the element. If this is the case, then no matter how you cut it, you will have to merge all the values somewhere to a key in memory to get the correct index.

If you don't care about getting the specific index like you have in the above example then take a look at the following code. This code assigns each element to a random partition within each key. This helps to break up the number of elements per key into something manageable.

```
data = [
  (k, c) for k in range(1, 6) for c in ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
]

p = beam.Pipeline()
elems = p | beam.Create(data)

num_buckets = 4

class Preprocess(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, el):
    key = str(el[0])
    partition = random.randint(0, num_buckets)
    yield (key, partition), el

class Postprocess(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, el):
    (key, partition), values = el
    index = 0
    for el in values:
      yield key, (el[1], partition, index)
      index += 1
    
out = (elems | beam.ParDo(Preprocess())
             | beam.GroupByKey()
             | beam.ParDo(Postprocess()))
```

Input

```
key,value
1   A
1   B
1   B
1   B
2   A
2   B
2   B
2   B
3   A
3   B
...
```

Potential Output

```
key,(value,partition,index)
1   ('A', 1, 0)
1   ('B', 1, 1)
1   ('B', 2, 0)
1   ('B', 3, 0)
2   ('A', 3, 0)
2   ('B', 3, 1)
2   ('B', 1, 0)
2   ('B', 1, 1)
3   ('A', 3, 0)
3   ('B', 2, 0)
...
```

[1] When using streaming it is defined per-key-per-window

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but it gave me an idea to help solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Np! If possible, it would be great if you could add an answer to how you solved it. I would love to know what solution you came up with.

Comment: Heyl I am kinda new to Beam and trying to understand it; Can you point me to the resource which reveals inner working of Beam which can help me come to the conclusion of this statement that you made, "the Beam model processes keys in parallel but values in a single key sequentially."